# Mysql: where ..id != X doesn't include the NULL foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, conditional-statements

I have this Mysql table:

assignment: assignment_id (PK), company_id (FK), ...some other fields...

The FK company_id can be NULL if an assignment is not yet assigned to a company.

Now, I want to query all assignments that are not for company with id 2. So I did:

```
SELECT * FROM assignment WHERE company_id != 2
```

To my surprise, assignments with company_id NULL aren't returned in the results. I'd say that NULL != 2 so it should be returned. It works fine if I go with

```
(company_id IS NULL OR company_id != 2)
```

Can someone explain me the logic behind this? Does it have to do with the FK constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is simple: you can't really say whether or not `NULL` is equal to 2, because you don't know anything about `NULL`. Quoting [**the doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html):

> Conceptually, `NULL` means **“a missing unknown value”** and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.  You cannot use arithmetic
>   comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for `NULL`. [...]
>   Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` is also
>   `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

You've already shown one possible workaround in your question, the other one is using `<=>` ([**NULL-safe comparison operator**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)):

```
SELECT * FROM assignment
WHERE NOT(company_id <=> 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Kind of strange that I've never run into this before in all my programming years.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not a number. It is a completely different thing in mysql. So you can not compare something to NULL. To clear your confusion, in your case, all the fields where FK is not 2 are those fields where the "value" is other than 2. But when the value is NULL, it means there is no value assigned at all.

See [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)